Search results undefined while loading from controller on Rails view
I am trying to do search functionality for my Rails MVC learning. I am adding title , description and category name as filter columns. And checking each parameter id defined in my model class using self method. But when loading view for first time, Its getting result as expected. But with parameters,  my article object is not getting any response in rails view,
My controller articles_controller.rb method,
def search

        @articles = Article.all
        if(params.has_key?(:title) || params.has_key?(:description) || params.has_key?(:name))
          @articles = Article.search_artcat(:params)
        end
         #render plain: params[:article][:title]
       
      end

My article.rb model file has,
def self.search_artcat(params)

    conditions = String.new
    wheres = Array.new

    if params.has_key?(:title)
      conditions << " AND " unless conditions.length == 0
      conditions << "title = ?"
      wheres << params[:title]
    end
    if params.has_key?(:description)
      conditions << " AND " unless conditions.length == 0
      conditions << "description = ?"
      wheres << params[:description]
    end
    wheres.insert(0, conditions)
 @article = Article.joins(:categories).where(wheres)
                 
end

And my view file search.html.erb,
  <h1>Search article</h1>
   <%= form_with scope: :article, url: search_path ,method: :get, data: { turbo: false}  do |f| %>
     <table>
      <td>
        <%= f.label :title %><br/> 
        <%= f.collection_select(:title, Article.all, :title, :title,{ prompt: "Select Title "}, { multiple: false}) %>
     </td>
     <td>
       <%= f.label :description %> 
       <%= f.collection_select(:description, Article.all, :description, :description,{ prompt: "Select Description "}, { multiple: false}) %>
    </td>
    <td>
     <%= f.label :name %>
     <%= f.collection_select(:name, Category.all, :name, :name,{ prompt: "Select Category "}, { multiple: false}) %>
    </td>
    <td>
     <%= f.submit %> 
    </td>
  <% end %>

<h3> Search Result </h3>

<% unless @articles.blank? %>
<table>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %> 
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.description %></td>

      <% article.categories.each do |cat|%>

          <td> <%= cat.name %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>

routes.rb file has
   resources :articles
   resources :categories, except: [:destroy]
   get 'search', to: 'articles#search'

And Article has many to many association through ArticleCategory
Can anyone one please guide to resolve or suggest any method to make implementation correctly?

@deugger- That was wrong copy paste. I added correct code


your where clause does not include table identifiers -- if you dump out the sql from your query you can see it will not work 2) why are you setting @article at the end of your search method -- just return the query 3) you can chain individual where clauses together -- no need to play around with matching the string and array

